# Unable to use the 'strcpy()' function. Generating error even after using #include <string.h>

Tags: c, arrays, string, gcc

**Practice.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char srce[]="abcd fghi jklmn";
  char dest[20];

  strcpy(dest,sizeof(srce),srce);

  printf("\n%s",dest);

  return 0;
}
```

**On Compilation I get this :**

```
Practice.c: In function 'main':
Practice.c:9:3: warning: passing argument 2 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer
without a cast [enabled by default]
   strcpy(dest,sizeof(srce),srce);
   ^
In file included from Practice.c:2:0:
c:\mingw\include\string.h:57:39: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of
type 'unsigned int'
 _CRTIMP char* __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW strcpy (char*, const char*);
                                       ^
Practice.c:9:3: error: too many arguments to function 'strcpy'
   strcpy(dest,sizeof(srce),srce);
   ^
```

Did I wrote the syntax of `strcpy()` wrong, or my code is not correct?

> Links to **Books & Web Pages** for the study of **Arrays, Strings, Pointers & Structs** will be appreciated.

Currently I m using `Apress: Beginning C 5th Edition`.

Comment: The error message is quite clear, argument mismatch, read them carefully. Read the manual of `strcpy` and `strncpy`.

Comment: @VSP I have added tutorial link in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct usage of the function is:

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

You can check [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) for more information.

**Edit:**

You can study the C tutorials from [this page](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html).

Answer (score 3):

The strcpy requires only 2 arguments.
The source string pointer and the destination string pointer.
You can remove the 2nd parameter "sizeof(srce)"

Comment: But this was the syntax in the book I m currently using.

Comment: If so, get rid of that book

Comment: @Quentin Could u provide me the answers to the last 3 lines of my Question. Please, I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Matt McNaabb Could u provide me the answers to the last 3 lines of my Question. Please, I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes you wrong the syntax of strcpy wrong. Your code is not correct. "Gaurav" already explained this. The last two lines of your question are not questions.

Answer (score 2):

**SYNOPSIS** : **check the difference between `strcpy` and `strncpy`**.

`char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);`
`char *strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char srce[]="abcd fghi jklmn";
  char dest[20];

  strncpy(dest, srce, strlen(srce));

  printf("\n%s",dest);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: that won't work. `strlen(srce)` is only `15`, so no `'\0'` is at the end of `dest`. So the `printf` will overflow.